# Eigen values of 3D matrix

Tags: matlab

I have the 3-D matrix, H, where the 3rd dimension is of size 200000 and each dimension contains a 2*2 square matrix

```
H=reshape([imgx(:),imgxy(:),imgyx(:),imgy(:)]',2,2,[]);
```

I want to calculate the eigen values for all 200000 matrices. For it I am using the formula:

```
[V,D]=eig(H);
```

But the problem is, eig() does not work for 3-D matrices. How can this be solved **without using loops**?

Comment: you need to loop it for each of the 200,000 units, btw, this is not going to be fast without the parallel computing toolbox.

Comment: Yes, thats why I want to do it without loops. Let me edit the question please.

Comment: like I said, you will need the parallel computing toolbox to speed it up, or it will be really slow

Comment: Is there no other alternative. I mean without using parallel computing toolbox.

Comment: you could take a look at this: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27680-multiple-eigen-values-for-2x2-and-3x3-matrices it does claim to be faster than looping eigs, and it does work on large sets of 2x2 and 3x3 matrices, but I have not tested it myself.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this: you make a (sparse) block diagonal matrix `A`:

```
A = [a1  0  0 ...
      0 a2  0 ...
      0  0 a3 ...
      :  :  : \ ]
```

with `ai` for `1 < i < 200,000` the "page number" of your original array (3rd dimension). You can do this using `spdiags()`. Then, the eigenvalues of `A` are the eigenvalues of your original matrices.

However, there are a few problems with this approach. The association between the eigenvalues and which `ai` matrix they belong to is hard to reconstruct after using `eig(s)`. Plus, I think it's total overkill and not actually faster than a loop, because your submatrices are so small.

Since they all are 2×2, their [characteristic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#2.C3.972_matrices) are quadratic and exceedingly simple to solve. So why not do that manually:

```
% Compute the necessary factors
a = 1;
b = -H(1,1,:) - H(2,2,:);
c = H(1,1,:) .* H(2,2,:) - H(1,2,:) .* H(2,1,:);

% to be used in the quadratic formula:
lambda1 = (-b + sqrt(b.^2 - 4*a*c)) /2/a;
lambda2 = (-b - sqrt(b.^2 - 4*a*c)) /2/a;
```

with `H` your original 3D array. Since `a = 1`, this simplifies to

```
sqdiscr = sqrt(b.*b - 4*c);
lambda1 = -b + sqdiscr;
lambda2 = -b - sqdiscr;
```

Comment: Yeah, since it is only 2x2 the direct calculation method is the way to go imo.